# PayPal express checkout not returning transaction id

Tags: php, paypal

I have downloaded the paypal express checkout code from this url

```
https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Express-Checkout-example
```

When i click on the button it is redirecting to the paypal page but not populating the amount on paypal site and also am not getting the transaction id, but the payment is working correctly.Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some sample code you have used. I'm also posting the following link which helps me in a similar case of problem.

[Paypal SandBox IPN always returns INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746644/paypal-sandbox-ipn-always-returns-invalid/11796543#11796543)

Comment: i have downloaded the code from --- https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Express-Checkout-example and changed only the api key and other details

Answer (score 0):

You're likely only calling the `SetExpressCheckout` API call. You'll also need to call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API once your buyer hits your 'RETURNURL' page in order to complete the transaction.

See also my answer at [Missing amount and order summary in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206175/missing-amount-and-order-summary-in-paypal-express-checkout/8213842#8213842)