# Paypal integration to accept credit card payment directly

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card

I have a question regarding PayPal integration with my website. I have a Premier account with PayPal. I tried integrating it with my website by adding a 'Buy Now' button. When I click on it it asks the end user to create a PayPal account. However, I want the users to be able to make a payment directly with their credit/debit card without creating a PayPal account.

I am not a technical guy, so I might have missed out on something. I want to know if it is possible to integrate paypal without me having to code something technically. Kindly advise.

Comment: I think you can do this with express checkout -- read their api docs about it.

Comment: And here is my answer with example url requests for Express Checkout. No account required, no shipping address(digital goods), show item details on checkout page and merchant transaction history. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638936/185565

Answer (score 3):

According to PayPal, buyers do not need a PayPal account to pay you:

> They can pay with their credit/debit card (Visa, MasterCard, American
>   Express, and Discover) — all without having a PayPal account.

Sources: [Do my buyers need a PayPal account to pay me?](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing_CommandDriven/merchant/wpstandard/WPStandardFAQsBFTwo-outside#Q3) and [Buttons for single purchases](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside)

To create the button, simply visit PayPal's button creator wizard and supply the required information.  Once submitted, PayPal will autogenerate the HTML for you.  See: [Create PayPal payment button](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=7hPHC5JJ6XowlUTMXfWRU-8xe8pAvRPRX0GWZ8FE6F_bEFsYRORZGPkAafG&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8da6a0e86558d6153d7722c6eea13ecd7b)

Comment: I think, if they spend more than around 1000GBP or 15000EUR in a lifetime the money sender needs an account.  This is due to banking regulation designed to limit money laundering in light of Sept11.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that exception.  Post your source to help @Anishphilipjohn, thanks.

Comment: I too read on the website that it is possible to not have a paypal account, and yet make a payment. I wanted to know how it could be done.

Comment: Yes it can be done.  It acts like a regular credit card payment processor.  The sender only provides basic details without needing to signup to Paypal (although the sender still accepts some legal terms while making payment).

Comment: @Anishphlipjohn since they've stated that a it isn't a requirement, I would create the button using their interface [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=gZ9HUWAZpOG1PN17mKmlXq-JK2duCadXBuNe-uoMeMlb3mcgrRmS8tXbwGe&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8da6a0e86558d6153d7722c6eea13ecd7b) just to be sure you haven't left out some crucial flag.  If it continues to require a user account, then I would perhaps send an email to their support [here](https://www.x.com/developers/how-can-we-help-you).

Comment: Thats great to know. Could you please let me know how to do it as well. Please keep in mind that i am not a technical guy.

Comment: My added comment on the limit relates to the sender regularly using their CC and details with paypal (possibly through multiple vendors) does have lifetime limits.  I have hit this myself being forced to signup to send money.  I do not have a reference to cite since I don't think it is a good marketing matter for paypal.  It is obfustacted with their unverified limits documentation.  Behind the scenes an unverified account is setup on behalf of a CC money sender to send any money.

Comment: @AnishPhilipJohn to create the button you can use their button creator interface [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=7hPHC5JJ6XowlUTMXfWRU-8xe8pAvRPRX0GWZ8FE6F_bEFsYRORZGPkAafG&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8da6a0e86558d6153d7722c6eea13ecd7b).  Fill in the required information such as the price and any additional charges and it will autogenerate the html for you.

Comment: Also @AnishPhilipJohn I would consider Darryl's comment and perhaps send a support email for further verification just so you aren't hit with any surprises.

Comment: @Jeremy I tried adding the button even earlier. But then it still asks me to input login details or create a new login. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @AnishPhilipJohn I decided to try this for myself.  It does bring up a form requiring buyer information, but it does say to "Pay as a guest now, sign up for PayPal later".  It looks to me like it needs this information at a minimum to verify the billing information attached to the buyer's credit card for security purposes.  I suppose I would want this if someone found my credit card somewhere and decided to go on a spending spree, whilst not knowing my billing information would prevent them from doing so.

Comment: I mailed support, and I have my answer. "this feature is not yet available to PayPal accounts in UAE"

Comment: Interesting.  Good to know.  Didn't realize this was strictly for UAE purchases.  Just a suggestion, add that nugget of info to your question, then add (and accept) your answer in order to help other readers.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because the account was a PayPal account in UAE, and this feature is not enabled there yet.

Comment: Do you know where one can find a list of countries - where this feature is available and where is not?