# Is it possible to personalize Paypal transaction description?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, nvp

I'm here to ask if is possible, and then how, to personalize the Paypal transaction description, for instance the one that the seller can see in the notification e-mail and in the transaction details on his Paypal account page.
Here a link to a screenshot (I can't post images yet!):

http://www.nssfactory.com/so/ppd.png

Now is a standard message: "Purchase from NAME OF THE SHOP", the client asked me if I can instead write there some details of the transaction, like the stock code, product name ecc..

FYI I'm using a built-on-my-own shop

FYI#2 I'm passing all products, shipments, discounts informations to the transaction, and they show correctly in the purchase sidebar, but the description I need to change remains the standard one, and I wasn't able to find anything in the new Paypal documentation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at my answer in [Missing amount and order summary in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206175/missing-amount-and-order-summary-in-paypal-express-checkout/8213842#8213842)

You'll want to be passing us the item details in the `SetExpressCheckout` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API calls.

If you only include this data in `SetExpressCheckout`, it'll be displayed on checkout but not on receipts.
If you include it in both `SetExpressCheckout` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, it'll persist and be displayed on both checkout and receipts / transaction details.