# PayPal Order Summary is empty

Tags: php, paypal, zen-cart

I use Express Checkout API (Name-Value Pair) to do the PayPal checkout. The problem is the login screen doesn't show Order Summary. I tried to set the below params like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572878/php-paypal-express-checkout-problem/7587393#7587393) but it still shows empty info.

```
$options["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC"] = "hieutot";
$options["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = "123";
$options["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = 300;
$options["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";

$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"] = "zzz";
$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"] = 1;
$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"] = 1000.00;

$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1"] = "test";
$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1"] = 1;
$options["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1"] = 200.00;
```

[image]

But when I tried to generate 10486 transaction error. The order summary appears! What a strange problem! How to fix it? Could it be a PayPal API bug? I'm using Zend Cart 1.3.8.
[image]

This is the request and response using cURL

```
REQUEST
Array
(
    [ITEMAMT] => 0.00
    [LOCALECODE] => US
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [EMAIL] => sorryICannotShowThis@gmail.com
    [PHONENUM] => xxxxxxxx
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => SOLE
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => hieutot
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 123
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 300
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => zzz
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 1000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => test
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 200
    [AMT] => 3,700.00
    [RETURNURL] => https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fipn_main_handler.php%3Ftype%3Dec
    [CANCELURL] => https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Findex.php%3Fmain_page%3Dshopping_cart%26amp%3Bec_cancel%3D1
    [PAGESTYLE] => Primary
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [CURRENCYCODE] => JPY
)

RESPONSE
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => sorryICannotShowThis
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d11%2d21T08%3a37%3a09Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 35adcd4bd76d5
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 3%2e2
    [BUILD] => 8549850
    [CURL_ERRORS] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check the VERSION used in your API requests:

> [VERSION] => 3%2e2

I'd suggest to use any version above 63.0 (which can support Line item)

See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

"This field is introduced in version 53.0. L_NAMEn is deprecated since version 63.0. Use L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAMEm instead."